# Activity has been destroyed after pressed home button in Android 12

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-lifecycle, android-12

I have two Activities, A is default launchMode, A start B, launchMode of B is singleInstance， then press home button , onDestroy method of A has been called, why?
my device is Pixel 3XL， android version is 12

Comment: The question is: why not? The OS is free to destroy any activity that's not currently in the foreground: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#asem

Comment: is this not similar to what you asked a few hours ago https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71126769/redmi-miui-activity-has-been-destroy-with-system

Comment: @a_local_nobody I have deleted the issue, I found this issue also happens in android 12

Comment: @Thomas  but in android 10, A will not be destroyed, only happens in android12, so how can I prevent this from happening

Comment: You can't. It's how Android works. Read the docs to find out how to deal with it by preserving and restoring state.

Comment: Have you set `android:taskAffinity` on any of your `<activity>` definitions in the manifest? Please edit your question and post the `<activity>` definitions for your activities.